# Unknown error in cloning a linked list of random pointers

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, c++14

C++ code
There is C++ code for cloning a linked list
Please refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-linked-list-with-next-and-arbit-pointer/ for details

```
Node* getNewNode(int data)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node();
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->arb = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
Node * copyList(Node *head)
{
    Node *cur = head, *copy=NULL, *copy_cur, *next;
    while(cur)
    {
        if(!copy)
        {
            copy = getNewNode(cur->data);
            copy_cur = copy;
        }
        else
        {
            copy_cur->next = getNewNode(cur->data);
            copy_cur = copy_cur->next;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    copy_cur = copy;
    cur = head;
    while(cur)
    {
        next = cur->next;
        cur->next = copy_cur;
        copy_cur->arb = cur;
        copy_cur = copy_cur->next;
        cur = next;
    }
    copy_cur = copy;
    while(copy_cur)
    {
        copy_cur->arb = copy_cur->arb->arb->next;
        copy_cur = copy_cur->next;
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Could anyone please help me in understanding the error in this implementation.

Comment: The first `while` loop makes the copy (except that it doesn't set `arb` pointers, only `next`; effectively, it produces a singly linked list). The second `while` loop does something really weird - it tears the original list apart, making each node's `next` point to the corresponding node in the new list. You basically end up with two parallel singly-linked lists - the new one is connected with `next`, the original one is connected with `arb`, `next` pointers from the old one point to the new one, `arb` pointers from the new one point to the old one. This makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things need to be corrected in your code.
Your first while loop is only creating a new singly link list with next pointers set but not the "arb" pointers. Rather then creating a complete new list, just embed the new nodes in the original list only. It would be easier for you to set the random pointers afterwards.

```
Node newlyClonedNode = createNewNode(node->data);
newlyClonedNode->next = node->next;
node->next = newlyClonedNode;
```

Then again traverse the list and set the random pointers of new cloned nodes.

```
node->next->arb = node->arb->next;
```

Once you have done that, break the new list from original list, thus you get your original list back plus the new cloned list with random pointers set.

```
Node clonedNode = node->next;
node->next = node->next->next;

clonedNode->next = clonedNode->next->next;
```